# Returning multiple object properties in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm able to return the CategoryName field into a list via `ViewBag.Categories`. I also want to return the `CategoryId` field and use it to dynamically build the category Details view URL

This is the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Details(Item item)
{
    var db = new appContext();
    ViewBag.Item = item.ItemTitle;
    ViewBag.ItemLink = "http://localhost:4444/Items/Details/" + item.ItemId;
    ViewBag.Categories = new List<string>(item.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryName));

    return View();
}
```

This is the view where the list of categories is returned:

```
@foreach (string category in ViewBag.Categories)
{
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:4444/Categories/Details/???">@category</a>
    </li>
}
```

How can I return `CategoryId`as shown above?

Comment: I recommend you use @Html.Action("Details", "Categories", new { ID = category.ID }) (based on dotnetoms' answer) to create the link. As soon as you publish your hard coded string above (..//localhost:4444/..) to a server  it will fail. Similarly `ViewBag.ItemLink should just be the ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom class for storing categories:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Assign it like this:

```
ViewBag.Categories = item.Categories
    .Select(c => 
        new CategoryViewModel 
        { 
            CategoryId = c.CategoryId, 
            CategoryName = c.CategoryName
        }).ToList();
```

And in your view use it like this:

```
@foreach (CategoryViewModel category in ViewBag.Categories)
{
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:4444/Categories/Details/@category.CategoryId">@category.CategoryName</a>
    </li>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous types to achieve this:

```
public ActionResult Details(Item item)
{
    var db = new appContext();
    ViewBag.Item = item.ItemTitle;
    ViewBag.ItemLink = "http://.../Items/Details/" + item.ItemId;
    ViewBag.Categories = item.Categories.Select(c => new { c.CategoryName, c.CategoryId });

    return View();
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
{
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:4444/Categories/Details/@(category.CategoryId)">@category.CategoryName</a>
    </li>
}
```

However, you may want to consider replacing the `ViewBag` with strongly-typed models. It offers a lot of great benefits - including IntelliSense support.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `List<string>` you could use a:

```
List<Tuple<int, string>>
```

E.g.

```
ViewBag.Categories = item.Categories.Select(cat => 
       Tuple.Create(cat.CategoryID, cat.CategoryName)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a view-model like this:

```
 public class CustomViewModel
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Categories Categories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Categories
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }

    public ActionResult Details(Item item)
    {
        var db = new appContext();
        var model = new CustomViewModel{
            Item = item.ItemTitle,
            ItemLink = "http://localhost:4444/Items/Details/" + item.ItemId,
            Categories = (item.Categories.Select(c => 
                new Categories{ Id = c.Id,CategoryName= c.CategoryName})).ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

> and view like:

```
   @model Categories
   @foreach (Categories category in Model.Categories)
    {
      <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:4444/Categories/Details/@category.CategoryId">@category.CategoryName</a>
     </li>
    }
```